# How to examine an apt repository?

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to set up riak on Debian wheezy. I've followed [their instructions](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/debian-ubuntu/#Installing-From-Apt-Get) to add the basho apt repositories...

```
$> curl http://apt.basho.com/gpg/basho.apt.key | sudo apt-key add -
$> sudo bash -c "echo deb http://apt.basho.com $(lsb_release -sc) main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/basho.list"
```

... and performed `apt-get update`:

```
...
Hit http://apt.basho.com wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://apt.basho.com wheezy Release
Hit http://apt.basho.com wheezy/main i386 Packages
Ign http://apt.basho.com wheezy/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://apt.basho.com wheezy/main Translation-en
...
```

However apt still says there's no such package:

```
$> apt-get install riak
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package riak
```

I suspect their instructions might be out of date, having an old package name. How can I query the basho apt repositories to see what packages it holds? I think that if I saw the list of packages, I could see which one it was that I wanted.

Comment: Note also that an apt repos that is served via http is just a bunch of static data. You can just go in and poke around using a web browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use aptitude to check which packages provides an specific site:

```
aptitude search '?origin(Unofficial Multimedia Packages)'
p   2mandvd                         - Video DVD creator                         
p   2mandvd:amd64                   - Video DVD creator                         
p   2mandvd-data                    - Video DVD creator (data files)            
p   aac-enc                         - Fraunhofer FDK AAC Codec Library - fronten
p   aac-enc:amd64                   - Fraunhofer FDK AAC Codec Library - fronten
p   aacgain                         - Lossless mp4 normalizer with statistical a
p   aacgain:amd64                   - Lossless mp4 normalizer with statistical a
p   aacplusenc                      - High-Efficency AAC (AAC+) Encoder.        
p   aacplusenc:amd64                - High-Efficency AAC (AAC+) Encoder.        
p   aacskeys                        - Decrypt all required keys from an AACS pro
p   aacskeys:amd64                  - Decrypt all required keys from an AACS pro
p   acroread                        - Adobe Acrobat Reader: Portable Document Fo
p   acroread-data                   - data files for acroread                   
p   acroread-debian-files           - Debian specific parts of Adobe Acrobat Rea
p   acroread-debian-files:amd64     - Debian specific parts of Adobe Acrobat Rea
p   acroread-dictionary-en          - English dictionary for for acroread       
p   acroread-escript                - Adobe EScript Plug-In                     
p   acroread-fonts-jpn              - Japanese fonts for Adobe acrobat reader
```

Or worse, you could just parse the package list directly:

```
grep Package /var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.deb-multimedia.org_dists_jessie_main_binary-i386_Packages 
Package: 2mandvd
Package: 2mandvd-data
Package: aac-enc
Package: aacgain
Package: aacplusenc
Package: aacskeys
Package: acroread-debian-files
Package: acroread-fonts-jpn
Package: advancemenu
Package: aften
```

Answer (score 4):

`apt-cache` is the program to use. You could do:

```
apt-cache search riak
```

to search everything and:

```
apt-cache --names-only search riak
```

to search only package names.

You can also limit `apt` activities to a single `.list` file using the `Dir::Etc::sourcelist` and `Dir::Etc::sourceparts` options. This should work with any `apt` command. Eg:

```
apt-cache -o Dir::Etc::sourcelist="/etc/apt/sources.list.d/basho.list" \
  -o Dir::Etc::sourceparts=/dev/null
  search raik
```